# i want to convert date fromat: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

Tags: java, jdbc

Response from jsp is coming in this format: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm", and I want to convert to db format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".

I tried this code :

```
public java.sql.Date getdateFormat(String datestring) throws ParseException {
    String datestr = "";
    try {
        java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a",
                Locale.ENGLISH).parse(datestring);
        atestr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return getDateFromString(datestr);

}


public java.sql.Date getDateFromString(String string) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date finalDate = null;
    try {
        finalDate = sdf.parse(string);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new java.sql.Date(finalDate.getTime());

}
```

Comment: *"i want to convert to db format"* Why? When interacting with the DB, you're using `PreparedStatement` and such, right? So you'll give it `Date` instances, not strings. You're not using string concatenation to create your DB queries, right? Because...http://xkcd.com/327/ :-)

Comment: What is your question?  Did you get an error or was the date format incorrect?

Comment: I assume you know that a `java.sql.Date` is only the date (without time), if you also want time you should use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake in using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is skip the documentation and assume that is knows when `mm` means months and when `mm` mean minutes.  It doesn't.  `mm` only means minutes.  If you want months use `MM`  Also only use `a` if you expect AM/PM and only use `hh` for 12 hour clocks.  I would expect your format should read

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm
```

and your output

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

BTW You shouldn't need to convert to a String to use JDBC.  Using a Date is faster and less error  prone.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the `Date` then you do not need to do

```
atestr=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(date);
```

simply return the `date` as this stage.

A date does not have any formatting, it is basically a number.

Comment: Also `hh` is for 12 hours, `HH` is for 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would basically do it like this

```
        String dateInString = "20140611";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        Date toDate = sdf.parse(dateInString);

        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String tmpStr = String.format(sdf.format(toDate));

        System.out.println(tmpStr);
```

Answer (score -1):

We can get the date in the following way

```
DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date parseDate = dfm.parse(datestring);
```

Now the `parseDate` is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"